# File encoding in UTF8 is truncating my file

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I need to extract a Data Extension of Contacts with several million lines in UTF8.

It works properly when I extract Sent, Open or Click data views but, here, I really can't figure out what is going on. The biggest difference I can see is that the Contacts DE is a Sendable DE...

I have only 1,2M lines in my extract when I use a Data Extract activity to convert in UTF8. When I don't do it, I have all my 8M lines available.

To give more details, I do :
1- SQL query to have all my contacts in a DE
2- Data extract to extract the DE
3- Data extract to convert in UTF8
4- File transfert to send to our FTP
5- Data extract to zip the file

I have all the needed lines when I dont run the conversion in UTF8.
I tried to invert steps 3 and 4 but I have the same result.

Do you have any idea of what I can check ?

Thanks !

David

Comment: Does your data have any characters utf8 doesn’t like?

Comment: I can't find... do you have examples ? 
The file I'm able to download seems to take the SFID in an alphabetical order and the next one (which is then in my DE but not in my file) seems OK to me... For now I don't find any reason

Comment: I checked the last line and finally found what was the problem, it's an : í
That's a very commun letter in spanish or portuguese so I'm not sure how to deal with this...

Comment: Perhaps run a query with a replace function to remove these characters

Comment: I have several other characters which makes trouble, so it won't be a long term solution. I guess I'll ask MC support to see what they think about this.